# Error while building Angular app with agm-spiderfier

Tags: angular, agm

1. I a getting error while compiling my code with AGM Spidefier library
   \node_modules\agm-spiderfier\index.ts is missing from the TypeScript compilation. Please make sure it is in your tsconfig via the 'files' or 'include' property.
2. Below are my tsconfig.app.json and tsconfig.spec.json

tsconfig.app.json

```
      {
         "extends": "./tsconfig.base.json",
         "compilerOptions": {
          "outDir": "./out-tsc/app",
           "types": []
        },
      "files": [
        "src/main.ts",
        "src/polyfills.ts"
      ],
      "include": [
        "src/**/*.d.ts",
        "../node_modules/agm-spiderfier/*.ts"
      ]
    }
```

tsconfig.spec.json

```
    {
      "extends": "./tsconfig.base.json",
      "compilerOptions": {
        "outDir": "./out-tsc/spec",
        "types": [
          "jasmine",
          "googlemaps"  
        ]
      },
      "files": [
        "src/test.ts",
        "src/polyfills.ts",
        "../node_modules/agm-spiderfier/index.ts",    
      ],
      "include": [
        "src/**/*.spec.ts",
        "src/**/*.d.ts",
        "../node_modules/agm-spiderfier/*.ts"
      ]
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    Please modify your both the files as below.
    
    tsconfig.app.json
    
    "include": [
        "src/**/*.d.ts",
        "node_modules/agm-spiderfier/**/*.ts"
      ]
    

tsconfig.spec.json
    
     "include": [
        "src/**/*.spec.ts",
        "src/**/*.d.ts",
        "node_modules/agm-spiderfier/**/*.ts"
      ]
```